# Using C++ template with std::function and std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I am trying to create a template class which would in turn generate a wrapper over a function. The class will then return the wrapper as result. I would like to use template to have general class that will work with any function with different signatures, such as:

1. `std::function<void()>task = std::bind(fun1, param1, param2);`
2. `std::function<int(int, int)>task = std::bind(fun2, param1, param2);`

I would like to have something like this:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A {
  A (string param1, string param2) {
    // The created wrapper here i.e. 'task' will be returned by the class.
    function<T1>task = bind(T2, param1, param2);
  }

  // Return the created wrapper in the constructor.
  function<T1> returnWrapper() {
    return task;
  }
};
```

The code above is mostly a pseudo code since it cannot be compiled, but gives an idea about what I am looking for. Is there any solution for this? I think there should be more than simply use a template for a function's signature. Any help would be highly appreciated. I also would like to be able to pass arbitrary number of parameters to 'bind' if possible.

Comment: If you could do this, how would you call it later?

Comment: I didn't write the complete pseudo code, but the intention is that the class will return the wrapper so it can be called later. In this case the class should return 'task'.

Comment: Ah, at first I thought you wanted to result in one common non-template type that could hold any kind of function. But I see the type would still depend on the function type `T1`.  `A(string, string)` is a constructor, which can't return anything. You mean `task` would be a class member you can access later? Or maybe an object of type `A` could be directly callable.

Comment: What is it you are binding? The two examples mention something named `fun` - but `A`'s constructor doesn't take one as a parameter. What is it supposed to be, and where is it supposed to come from? Let's put it this way: suppose you managed to implement a class just the way you want it. Show a concrete example of how you would use it.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik: I actually wanted to use template to be able to use it for any kind of function and generate arbitrary wrapper. I edited the question so fun1 and fun2 are used. I would like to use it like this:

function<int(void())> ff = A<int(void()), OriginalFuncName>("param1", "param2");

Comment: Why not simply `function<int(void())> ff = std::bind(OriginalFuncName, "param1", "param2");` ? Anyway, `A` takes a type as its second template parameter; it doesn't look like `OriginalFuncName` is a type, but rather a function pointer (though without a [mcve] it's hard to be sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem! I had to define a class which takes two type names inside a template and pass one of them to std::function as function signature after currying and use the second one in the constructor to define the curried function (result function after wrapping) in std::bind. Then everything worked fine! There might be some better solution, but this was the best and more or less clear solution I got. Here is the got snippet of the solution I found! Hope it helps the other with the same issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class A {
  private:
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    class B { 
      private:
        function<T1>ff;

      public:
        B(T2 fun) {
          ff = bind(fun, 1, placeholders::_1);
        }

        virtual ~B() {
        }

        int exec(int x) {
          return ff(x);
        }
    };

    static int myFun(int x, int y) {
      return x + y;
    }

  public:
    A() { 
    };

    int test() {
      B<int(int), int (*)(int, int)> b(&myFun);
      return b.exec(10);
    }

    virtual ~A() {
    };
};

int main() {
  A a;

  // Correct result is '11' since we pass 11 and 1 is in the curried function.
  cout << "test result: " << a.test() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```